# How to get URL template path in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm working on ActionFilter and need to get URL template path like `/api/v{version}/controllerName/actionName/{parameter}`. However, the solution needs to be generic so it supports multiple URL patterns like `api/v{version}/controllerName/actionName/{parameter}/otherActionName/{otherParameter}`.

ASP.NET Core 2.2 latest stable. What I have is `ActionExecutedContext` which contains `HttpContext` as well. However, I am not sure about the content of this `HttpContext` since it contains some default values for the response.

```
    private PathString GetUrlTemplatePath(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        // TODO:
        return context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
    }
```

Actual result: `/api/v1/Location/addresses/999999A1-458A-42D0-80AA-D08A3DAD8199`.

Expected result: `/api/v{version}/location/addresses/{externalId}` where `externalId` is a name of parameter described by an attribute `[HttpGet("addresses/{externalId}", Name = "GetAddress")]`.

Comment: just wondering why you would need that?

Comment: Suggest you provide a minimal complete example.  As asked it's not clear what you want.

Comment: @DanielA.White Action filter to collect Prometheus metrics on a controller. I need this template path for a label on a metric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the template path from your `ActionExecutedContext` from your ResourceFilter. if you need `QueryString` for your problem or there is `ActionArguments` in the context of type `Dictionary<string, object>`which contains all the parameters passed with the request.

```
//template
string template = context.ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo.Template;;

//arguments
IDictionary<string, object> arguments = context.ActionArguments;

//query string
string queryString= context.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.Value;
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get part of it from the `context.ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo`. I'm not 100% sure if that would be complete or just a partial piece of it.